# Got the same message from an employer twice in 4 hours

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I don't know if it is a mistake of the system or if this employer is just being over-eager. But an employer maybe shouldn't be allowed to send the same job advertisement twice in one day to the same person.

Not exactly sure whether to tag this as a bug, feature-request, or support

Comment: Same thing happened to me.

Comment: Oh sure.  You guys just want to show off that you're in demand!  ;-P

Comment: Nice to know the competition, though, isn't it.  Assuming, of course, only one employer has done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now block multiple requests (probably accidental) from employers if an existing request is already "in flight"